# OpenMP. Нетривиальный случай

Tags: c++, openmp

Аналог реальной программы. Как переместить создание потоков (#pragma omp parallel) в main_, но оставить funcSerial однопоточным (последовательным)? funcSerial я распараллеливать пробовал - толку мало. В реальной программе там идет очень интенсивный обмен с памятью, и более чем в два раза она не ускоряется на любом количестве ядер.

```
   double funcPar()
    {
        double sum[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    #pragma omp parallel
        {
    #pragma omp for
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)  //loop body should be parallel (multy-threaded)
            {
                auto a = (double)i;
                sum[i] += sin(a)*cos(a); // real code is more complicated and works much longer
            }
        }//omp parallel
        return sum[0] + sum[1] + sum[2] + sum[3];
    }
    double funcSerial() //function should remain serial (single-threaded)
    {
        int K = 5000;
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int k = 0; k < K; k++)
        {
            sum += funcPar();
        }
        return sum;
    }
    void main_() // //function body should remain serial (single-threaded)
    {
        int J = 1000;
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int j = 0; j < J; j++)
        {
            sum += funcSerial();
        }
        printf("\n\n sum = %f \n", sum);
    }
```

Comment: Вопрос звучит как "распараллеилить функцию funcSerial, оставив ее однопоточной"

Comment: А что Вам мешает написать те же `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)` для цикла в `main()`? Пытаться делать параллельным вложенный цикл, мягко говоря, неэффективно (если функции на каждой итерации выполняются быстрее или хотя бы столько же времени, чем получается на запуск/остановку потока). И еще менее эффективно - делать это внутри второго вложенного цикла (как это сейчас у Вас, в функции `funcPar()`).

Comment: @Vladimir Цикл в main я распараллеливал. Это приводит к тому, что число вызовов funcSerial растет, что приводит к перегрузке шины памяти, как я уже писал. Двухратное ускорение максимум.

Comment: @Vladimir Конечно я понимаю что не эффективно создавать потоки в последнем вложенном цикле, поэтому и спрашиваю, как создание потоков перенести в main, и сделать это так, чтобы цикл в main, и funcSerial выполнялись одним потоком.

Comment: @VTT это часть вопроса. Однопоточной также должна остаться main. Потоки должны создаваться в main.